# Navigation Drawer Android API specific Layout Attribute

Tags: android, api, layout

Hello I have created a navigation drawer with ListView navigation using `ActionBar Sherlock` and `android support Library v4` for old version compatbility (my app's minSdkversion="8") in which I have used some attributes for textview in ListView:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

This is showing error as `?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator` is from API 11 and `?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall` & `?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall` are from API 14.

I managed to support `?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator` by replacing it with actionBar Sherlock's `?attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator`. But I didn't find any equivalence for other two attributes. There is `?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall` in actionBar Sherlock but it is not properly working.

So what are the equivalence for these attributes to provide support all the API above 2.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you really need to use android dimensions (like `listPreferredItemHeightSmall` etc.) In some android version can that dimension be 12 and in other 14. I suggest you to create your own dimension, which will be used in your whole app, and you can easily edit them when change is needed.

Comment: Hello, I have solved it by setting 
`<dimen name="textview_height">50dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="font_size">18sp</dimen>`
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Also a question.This custom dimension seems perfect. But are these dimensions vary from android standard dimensions? I mean, what are values of android API for this dimensions?

Comment: You can find those dimensions in android sdk. It doesn't matter if dimensions are different, if your layouts look like you want and you follow android design patterns.

Answer (score 32):

To support lower versions, instead of removing the following three parameters,

```
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" 
  android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
```

You can actually **replace** them with equivalent values/resources.

The equivalent values can be obtained from
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Now,

- **a)** `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"`
- **b)**

  1. Download a selector from 
     https://github.com/habzy/Test0011_DialerPad/blob/master/res/drawable/list_item_activated_background.xml
  2. In the above project browse the resources in hdpi,mdpi etc and get files named **list_activated_holo.9.png**
  3. Finally

  `android:background="@drawable/list_item_activated_background"`
- **c)** From the equivalent values obtained , we know that  **listPreferredItemHeightSmall** is 48dip

  `android:minHeight="48dip"`

Comment: you can also create API specific styles in values, values-v11 e t.c.

Comment: I think there are some corrections needed in step b.  These names don't match.