# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-inflate

I am getting error when trying to run this code in gingerbread 2.3.The code works fine in jellybean. The above code has support library called Sherlock. I'm still unable to run in ginger bread can anyone    help me out?

**Complete log**

```
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at com.androidbegin.sidemenututorial.MenuListAdapter.getView(MenuListAdapter.java:51)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1610)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1795)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:718)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:775)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1440)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 20:26:21.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from drawer_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        // Get the Title
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // Generate title
        title = new String[] { "Title Fragment 1", "Title Fragment 2",
                "Title Fragment 3" };

        // Generate subtitle
        subtitle = new String[] { "Subtitle Fragment 1", "Subtitle Fragment 2",
                "Subtitle Fragment 3" };

        // Generate icon
        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.action_about, R.drawable.action_settings,
                R.drawable.collections_cloud };

        // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass string arrays to MenuListAdapter
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainActivity.this, title, subtitle,
                icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        // Capture listview menu item click
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Set the title on the action when drawer open
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

        // Get the title followed by the position
        setTitle(title[position]);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
}
```

**Menulistadapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] mTitle;
    String[] mSubTitle;
    int[] mIcon;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle,
            int[] icon) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
        this.mIcon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mTitle[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtSubTitle;
        ImageView imgIcon;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,
                false);

        // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

        // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
        imgIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        // Set the results into TextViews
        txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
        txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);

        // Set the results into ImageView
        imgIcon.setImageResource(mIcon[position]);

        return itemView;
    }

}
```

**drawer_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com
/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawer_list.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
 android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
  </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In drawer_main.xml xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com
/apk/res/android" seems to span two lines, is that a copy paste error or is that how it is in the xml?

Comment: It is a copy paste error.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace and indicate which of the two layout files is the one causing the crash.

Comment: I have updated the complete log file.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to support android version lesser that v11 you will need to remove these lines in your drawer_list.xml file

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

those codes are only supported for version 11 or greater.

add `android:minHeight="48dip"` to your drawer_list.xml file

Solution follow this link for proper solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20123120/5761017